# Simple ASP Query Question

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I make the SelectCommand use a textbox from the default page so that I can add that to the where clause? Please include an example I am new to programming and it helps me understand the concept better. thanks in advance.

> Example WHERE (BADGE = 10000 + 
>   xBadgeTextBox.Text)?

```
string Badge = "100000" + Request.Form["xBadgeTextBox"];

 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="Time" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Time %>" 
         ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Time.ProviderName %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT CLOCK_IN_TIME, CLOCK_OUT_TIME, BADGE FROM CLOCK_HISTORY WHERE (BADGE = 100000342)"> // use the badge number instead.
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add parameters to the query and specify them within the SqlDataSource object.  Take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx

Also, please PLEASE be very careful of SQL injection attacks here.  At some point you may be tempted to just concatenate the string from the textbox to the select command.  Don't :)

Comment: I tried this but the gridview doesn't even show up on the aspx page, what am I doing wrong?
 
  
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Time %>" 
         ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Time.ProviderName %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT &quot;CLOCK_IN_TIME&quot;, &quot;CLOCK_OUT_TIME&quot; FROM &quot;CLOCK_HISTORY&quot; WHERE (&quot;BADGE&quot; = :BADGE)">
         <SelectParameters>
             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="xBadgeLabel" Name="BADGE" PropertyName="Text" 
                 Type="String" />
         </SelectParameters>
     </asp:SqlDataSource>

Comment: Unless it's just a copy/paste problem here, the instances of &quot; in the SelectCommand might be the culprit.  If that's what's being sent to the database, it'll probably just return an error.  Are you catching an error?

Comment: what if the string is already concatenated in the textbox "user enters 343 real number is 10000343", how can I get it to read the actual number?

Comment: no the &quot are put in by default in vs2008 I cant remove them or it wont run

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the string is already concatenated in the textbox."  In simplest terms, "343" != "10000343" and therefore wouldn't (shouldn't) return that record in the query.  This can be addressed by validators on the textbox that require the input be in a specific format.  As for the SQL Parameter, if all you're expecting from the user is "343" then this may be getting a little more business-logicy than these .NET 2.0 declarative objects can handle.  It may be worth the effort to put this in code instead.

Comment: All I want to display is the users Clock in and out time in the grid based on the users badge number entered in the TextBox on the main page. what I mean about its already concatenated is this in code it looks like this string Badge = "100000" + Request.Form["xBadgeTextBox"]; the user only has to enter a 3 digit number but in the database the real number is 9 characters long, I wanted to see if this was causing the issue.

Comment: I have tried it in code but it has proven to be even more difficult so today I thought I might try this method.